# how to use model in different controller in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a profile controller. But I want to use the User model to save some fields in the users table. So how can I load the User model in the profile controller?

Answer (score 15):

model are independent entity and you can call it from any controller.

```
There can be a model without a controller and vice-versa.
```

For you question take a example below

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController

  def some_method
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
       // some action
    else

       // some action
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can load any model in any controller - just call it as you would normally.

If you need to load a `User` from your `Profiles` controller, you can just use `User.find_by_whatever()`, `User.new`, `current_profile.user` - not sure how your associations are set up, but there shouldn't be any access restrictions.

Comment: when i use like
@user = User.new;
@a = User.find(:all)
it shows error "uninitialized constant ProfileController::User"
any thing am i missing?

Comment: You definitely have a User model set up? Can you call it fine from the Users controller, or isn't there one?